# How to fix 'Name is not defined' error in python

Tags: python

I'm getting error name is not defined it is showing like this:-

> Traceback (most recent call last):File "C:/Users/Shashank Kumar/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/ssss.py", line 1084, in changeBackgroundAnimation
>       DISPLAYSURF.fill(bgcolor)
>   NameError: name 'bgcolor' is not defined

```
def changeBackgroundAnimation(animationSpeed=40):
    global bgcolor
    newBgColor=(random.randint(0,255),random.randint(0,255),random.randint(0,255))
    newBgSurf=pygame.Surface((WINDOWWIDTH,WINDOWHEIGHT))
    newBgSurf=newBgSurf.convert_alpha()
    r,g,b=newBgColor
    for alpha in range(0,255,animationSpeed):
        checkForQuit()
        DISPLAYSURF.fill(bgcolor)
        newBgSurf.fill((r,g,b,alpha))
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(newBgSurf,(0,0))
        drawButtons()
        pygame.display.update()
        FPSCLOCK.tick(FPS)
    bgcolor=newBgColor
```

> NameError: name 'bgcolor' is not defined

Comment: In which line of the code you shared is the error? Does it ocurr in the `global bgcolor` line?

Comment: in DISPLAYSURF.fill(bgcolor)

Comment: As chepner answered, have you defined bgcolor elsewhere in the code?

Comment: `bgcolor` is defined as `global`. So it MUST be defined somewhere outside of your function. Add `bgcolor=0` before your `def `. What do you see?

Answer (score 1):

`global bgcolor` does not define, declare, or otherwise create a variable. It simply states that a global variable by that name, not a local variable, should be used. You still need to ensure it is defined before your first use in `DISPLAYSURF.fill(bgcolor)`. Specifically, you need to assign a value to the variable before the first time you call `changeBackgroundAnimation`.

Comment: please can you just show me where i have to change or what i have to change because i tried everything

Comment: @UdayPratapSingh Instead of doing `global bgcolor` define it by `bgcolor = Whatever`

Comment: I can't show you, because I don't know where you call the function. But you need some value assigned to it before you can use it to fill `DISPLAYSURF`.

Comment: yes just now i tried bgcolor=0 then no errors are showing but in my program this function is not working

Comment: Assigning *a* value fixed the problem in the question; whether you assigned a *valid* value, or whether your function is otherwise correct, is another question altogether.